# Hive non-equi joins

Tags: sql, apache, hive

How can covert the below query to hive without cross join ?

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE  TXN_DAY < (SELECT
                        MIN(TXN_DAY)
                        FROM TXN
                        WHERE ID = 2)
```

Is this the best possible solution ?

```
  select * from t1 join (SELECT
                        MIN(TXN_DAY)
                        FROM TXN
                        WHERE ID = 2) txn
   where t1.txn_day > txn.txn_day
```

I don't need to worry about cross join as anyway its going to get converted into map join ?

Comment: why do you think that you need cross join? you need inner join

Comment: yes...I meant I want to achieve without getting into cross join

Comment: so... don't use cross join